# Sequel Pro or other Non-Socket connections refused in MySql 5.6.26

Tags: mysql, macos

Ok, I have looked at about 15 answers to this question on here, and none of them work.

I am on a Mac, running OSX 10.10, MySql 5.6.26

Whenever I try to connect with Sequel Pro I get the following:

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.
```

My users are in my MySql dump, with grant on all of them to *.*

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Host                 | User     |
+----------------------+----------+
| %                    | macfelon |
| 127.0.0.1            | macfelon |
| 127.0.0.1            | root     |
| ::1                  | root     |
| localhost            |          |
| localhost            | macfelon |
| localhost            | root     |
| robert-macbook.local |          |
| robert-macbook.local | root     |
+----------------------+----------+
```

My port is open at 3306.  It connects with the Socket option, but not on Standard.

Nothing I can find seems to resolve this for me.

Comment: You're attempting with Sequel Pro, which seems to use a nonstandard error message. If you connect with the MySQL command line client to 127.0.0.1 does it succeed, or what error message is produced? Does the user have the same password for all connections?

Comment: And is MySQL configured to actually listen for TCP connections? Check `my.cnf` for the `bind-address` setting. By default in most installations, it is not enabled. You would need `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to listen for TCP (or specify the specific IP if you have multiple network adapters) or `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` for local TCP only.

Comment: Full Message
    Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.

    Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

    MySQL said: Access denied for user 'macfelon'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Added the binding:
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Same password for all connections, yes.  Not sure how to connect via the command line to 127.0.0.1

Comment: So it sounds like MySQL is really listening on 3306 and the client was able to open the connection via TCP, but maybe the password differs (MySQL's access is user+host+password). You might try connecting with the known good socket user and `SET PASSWORD FOR macfelon@localhost...` as well as `SET PASSWORD FOR macfelon@127.0.0.1`  The `%` record may complicate things too, but MySQL should try to use the 127.0.0.1 user before the % user.

Comment: Via the command line, you would use `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u macfelon -p`

Comment: On that command run, ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'macfelon'@'localhost' (using password: YES).  reset all passwords again, same error in Sequel Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain it's actually listening on port 3306? There's an answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/mac-os-x-10-10-mysql-5-6-26-accessible-from-cli-but-not-port-3306 where others are reporting that the configuration in my.cnf is being ignored, and for some reason MySQL 5.6.26 configures /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist to use port 3307 by default. Modifying that .plist to port 3306 solved this issue for me.

Comment: Yes, I never changed the default port.  It was a bad password set attempt on the wrong DB issue in the end